# Creating read more link in PHP for a dashboard

Tags: php

I have created a dashboard for my project. So for a big post I have added a "" link if it is more than 400 chars. and after clicking that link It should display the post's whole content. But what I have done according to that logic if I click on read more link every post of dashboard get expanded. I want only that particular post to be expanded. Plus the page reloads again..so To see the expanded post I have to scroll again. I know to do this without reloading I have to use AJAX or Js..But I am not getting the exact help to do it.
 Logic which I have used..

file 1-->dboard2.php

```
<?php echo strlen($b)>= 400? 
  substr($b, 0, 399).'<a href="dboard21.php">[Read more]</a>' : 
  $b; ;?><br/>
```

file 2-->dboard21.php

```
<?php echo $b.' <a href="dboard2.php">[less]</a>';
```

?>

all this is in a div tag which has container and all. so I want that particular div to expand,so how to pass that particular post's div?

Answer (score 0):

### Using CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #read-more {
        display: none;
    }

    #read-more:target {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<?php
    echo strlen($b) >= 400 ? 
    substr($b, 0, 399) . '<a href="#read-more">[Read more]</a><div id="read-more">' : 
    $b;
?>
<br/>
```